# Print hidden text except TC fields

Tags: printing, microsoft-word-2010, field-codes

In Word 2010, is it possible to print hidden text inside my document, except TC fields?

Indeed, I have a document which contains hidden text and some TC fields to generate the table of contents. Depending on the situation, I want to print the document without the hidden text or with the hidden text. However, under options, when activating the "Print hidden text" option, TC fields are also printed as those are basically just hidden text if I'm not mistaken. 
Is there a way to avoid this without having to go through the document and delete all of the TC fields before printing?

Comment: Have you considered using something other than TC fields to generate those entries in your TOC?

Comment: @Adam: Sorry for the delayed answer. I tried using heading styles. But when I hide the heading, it won't show up in the ToC. I don't know about any other means of creating a ToC. I finally resorted to write a macro which would basically change the hidden text (except the TC fields) to unhidden and then just print the document.